Where can I find a Jehovah's Witnesses version of a Hebrew Interlinear Old Testament?
Where can I find a Jehovah's Witnesses version of a Hebrew Interlinear Old Testament?
I'm at my wits' end googling for one.

The only "Interlinear" the Watch Tower Society has published was for their rendition of the Christian Greek Scriptures. They have never come out with their own rendition of the Hebrew Scriptures. So, you can stop searching!
The purple-covered Interlinear that I have was produced by the New World Bible Translation Committee in 1969, and there was a later, 1985 edition of that. To repeat, it was not the Old Testament. It only gave the Greek text of the New Testament as produced by Westcott and Hort, including their literal English word-for-word translation underneath the Greek. The side columns in English were the work of that Jehovah's Witness Committee.

one of the fundamental issues i have with your answer above...can you cite who actually wrote the NWT "Paraphrase" (it is not a translation) and also, who wrote the kingdom interlinear? What are the individuals names and what are their qualifications? As far as I am aware, the authors are anonymous are they not?

@adam That seems like an issue with Jehovah's Witnesses, rather than an issue with the answer. The first part has been asked already; if the second part hasn't, you should ask it.

I'm curious to know if the Watchower has addressed why they haven't

@adam The translation committee (as they call themselves) produced the Kingdom Interlinear Translation of the Christian Greek Scriptures (as they named their purple-covered book). They only wrote the English side columns and their footnotes. Nothing else, and not actual translation. The Greek text and literal word-for-word English underneath it was the work of Anglican scholars Westcott & Hort. Years later, a list of who the men were on that cmte was produced, and made public. Apparently, only one of them had basic Greek language education.

@another-prodigal  Only the Watchtower Society can answer your further Q. I have my own thoughts on why they never produced a Hebrew interlinear, but would not state them here. You could ask a new Q, though.

JW's have not published the authors of any of the material they have produced, whether music or literature, for the last nearly 100 years.

@MichaelR That is correct and confirmed by this footnote on p.608 of their 'Proclaimers' book, where the Translation Committee made the request to the W.T.B.&T.S of Pennsylvania "that the names of the translators never be published".  The Org. never published their names. However, a former member of the Governing Body had a relative on that Cmte. When Raymond Franz left the Soc. he was disfellowshipped and viewed as an apostate, publishing two books revealing such exclusive information as the names of those men on that translation cmte. They were his relative Frederick Franz,

Ganges, Henschell, Knorr and Schroeder. Only Franz had any basic knowledge of basic Greek. Because the book where those names were divulged, with hundreds more pages of insider information given, with proofs, was written by Raymond Franz who is viewed as an apostate, JWs are actively discouraged from reading any of his books. But the names are out there, in the public domain.

Jehovah's Witnesses have not produced a Hebrew Interlinear edition of the Old Testament.

these are the bible translations

Has the Watchtower addressed why it hasn't?

@another-prodigal The Greek Interlinear was originally made by Westcott and Hort (as mentioned by Anne). The Watchtower Society obtained the rights to it and continued its publication. Since the Watchtower Society didn't produce a Greek Interlinear themselves I don't see a reason why they would make a Hebrew Interlinear.
